# how to count occurrences of list of string in a string - new to python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a str and a list of str and wanted to count the number of times that list occurs in the str. How can i solve this??

I've tried this:

```
def count_from_word_list(s,l):
    """(str,list of str) -> int
    Return the total number of times l appears in the s
    """
    counter = 0

    for item in s.split():
        for item in l:
            if s == l:
                counter= counter + 1
    return counter
```

Comment: have you tried using Counter?

Comment: yes i have it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `container_string.count(contained_string)` to get a count of how many times a string contains another string!

For example:

```
>>> 'foofoofoo'.count('foo')
3
```